# how to download file from youtube using C#

Tags: c#, download, youtube

How do I download any video file from Youtube server. I am use this code to download file

```
        WebClient WClient = new WebClient();
        WClient.DownloadFile("Source address", "Destination");
```

but this method does not work with youtube.

Comment: Youtube videos are embedded, you can't download them this way. Check out this which should help you on your way - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube

Comment: are you find any solution on that then please also let me know i need also download you tube videos.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [**libvideo**](https://github.com/James-Ko/libvideo). It's very easy to use and is well documented.

(**Disclaimer:** I wrote it. Please enjoy!)

Comment: i am try using libvideo but doesn't getting youtube class and GetVideo() method. can you please let me know how can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [YoutubeExtractor](http://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor)

Answer (score -3):

You cannot download content from YouTube as it (most likely) breaks the [Terms of Service](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms).

> You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or
>   similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content. You
>   shall not copy, reproduce, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display,
>   sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content for

You could screen-scrape the download link, and then call DownloadFile on it's href.

Comment: This answer was not helpful because it just patronizes instead of showing a way of doing exactly what was asked